# How to properly remove hidden class from element when scroll reaches bottom with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page where i show 10 images. in the DOM there are x number of images. On scroll i want to show 5 images when the scroll hits the bottom. my problem is that nothing shows...

my code:

```
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
            $.pagen.helpers.loadData();
        }
    });
```

$.pagen.helpers.loadData(); function:

```
 $(".imageListContainer.hidden").slice(0, 5).removeClass("hidden");
```

What am I missing?

EDIT HTML:

```
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">
  <img data-theme="Energi" data-products="XXX" data-store="XXXXXX" data- date="2016-02-03" src="XXXX">
 </div>
```

Comment: can you post `imageListContainer` html?

Comment: I have added html. Format is a bit crazy for some reason. Appreciate if some1 can correct it

Comment: maybe its not the window thats scrolling, but its an inner element thats scrolling? Inspect the scroll bar to see where in the DOM the scroll bar is located.

Comment: @GeneralCarter thank you for opening my mind and puting reason in to it.
the scroll was on the DOM. I did had to add a +1 number for it to work but it works and im happy. i will post the answer as edit soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soloution:

```
    $(document).scroll(function (event) {

        if ($("#Tags").data("datefilteractive") == true || $("#Tags").data("filteractivated") == true)
            return false;

        var position = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        position = Math.round(position) + 1;

        if (position >= $(document).height()) {
            $.pagen.helpers.loadData();
            $(".imageListContainer.hidden").slice(0, 5).removeClass("hidden");
        }

        else {

         // something else
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons your code might not be working:

- the page content with the images hidden is not taller than the viewport, so `window.scroll` never fires
- `$.pagen.helpers.loadData()` is missing, was defined incorrectly, or is otherwise inaccessible
- Something obvious, such as forgetting to include jQuery
- It's not the window that's scrolling, but some other DOM element (added this to the list, as it turns out to have been the real cause here)

As you can see below, your code works if you replace the call to the loadData function with the contents of that function (watch the scrollbar tick upwards eatch time you hit bottom):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (
    $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
      $('.imageListContainer.hidden').slice(0, 5).removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>Extra text to force scroll<br>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
<div class="imageListContainer hidden">New element</div>
```

(One outlier possibility which I haven't confirmed: you test for the scroll position being greater than or equal to the document height. You may want to allow for a little extra slop in case of rounding errors or subpixel values in some browsers? (check for scroll position >= (document height minus 10px), say, instead of the exact height)  If the above snippet doesn't work in your browser, that'd confirm that this guess is correct)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem was that the scroll was on the DOM and not the window.